# add css class - jquery - rules

Tags: jquery, css

I have an element with a css class ".validate_txt_sContactPhone" and after this validation, would like to apply new css class to the element.

```
$(".validate_txt_sContactPhone").rules("add", {
          required: true,
          minlength: 2,
          messages: {
              required: "",
              minlength: jQuery.format("2*")
          }

      })
```

Comment: Do you want it to require a certain CSS class? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: If you are using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) then what you are looking for is the [validClass/errorClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) options to the `.validate()` function.

Comment: Is this to be taken as "How do I, when invalid, have jQuery validator add a custom CSS class to the element?"

Comment: Im sorry for not being clear. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) then what you are looking for is the [validClass/errorClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) options to the `.validate()` function.

I would recommend reading through all the options on that page, some that may be useful to you:

```
invalidHandler
success
errorClass
validClass
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I am not supposed that logic, company policy :) can you tell me remove next div element to this ".validate_txt_sContactPhone" in the above validation logic.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for at all. CSS classes (and callbacks) are registered through the `validate` function, not the `rules` interface because its not a rule.